# How to loop over lat and lon data(grid cells) and read files in a folder that corresponding with the chosen lat and lon from the grid cells

Tags: r

I have a task in which I need to calculate temperature and precipitation changes over specific place. To do so, I have grid cells data called in my script as "gc", which has three columns. one colume has the name of drainage that represents the area and the second and third columns are fpr lat and lon, respectively, for these drainages. Also, I have a folder that called in my script flux_data that has several files that have the data for the temperature and precipitation for these area ( the drainage in grid cells data).
so What I want to do is to loop over the grid cells data( drainage, lat and lon) and choose certain lat and lon from "gc", and then loop over the flux_data to see if the chosen lat and lon matches these files' name that are inside flux_data. My condition is that If they(lat and lon in "gc" data and files names in"flux_data" data) are matched, then i need to read this file and do some calculations in this file to get the temp. and percip. changes, and if there are not matched, then just skip this file and move to another file  and do the same test.
However, when I performed the loop it does not produce any results and my condition never met.

so, my question is how to do this loop correctly ? and how can I check on the name of files and see if they are the same as the lat and the lon in gc data so that I can perform my task under this condition.

```
setwd("/Users/salah95/FD")
```

## set up my flux folder that contains data files

flux_data <- list.files(pattern = "flux_*.")

## flux_data folder has these files :

```
flux_data
#[1] "flux_41.28125_-116.09375.txt" "flux_41.28125_-116.28125.txt"
#[3] "flux_41.34375_-116.03125.txt" "flux_41.46875_-115.46875.txt"
#[5] "flux_41.78125_-119.46875.txt" "flux_43.40625_-110.21875.txt"
#[7] "flux_43.53125_-110.21875"     "flux_48.40625_-117.15625"    
#[9] "flux_52.84375_-118.96875"
```

## next

```
gc=read.table(file='/Users/salah95/streamflow/bcccsm11/grid_cell_ids.txt', header=TRUE, sep = "")
```

## gc has the lat and lon for each drainage and I only need some drainages data not all of them

## this is how this grid cells data "gc" looks

head(gc)
Drainage      Lat      Long
#1    BONNE 43.40625 -109.7812
#2    BONNE 43.40625 -109.8438
#3    BONNE 43.40625 -109.9062
#4    BONNE 43.46875 -109.9062
#5    BONNE 43.84375 -109.9062
#6    BONNE 43.90625 -109.9062

> 

### next creat a loop :

### Now we will loop using nested for loop so that we can loop over gc and flux_data,

### -- in flux_data floder,  the files' names are named by the lat and the lon of the drainage, in which each file stores drainage's data such as the temperature and precipitation.

### therfore, I used the names' files to check if the lat and lon in gc matches the file name then read this file and perform some task on this file. If not, then just skip it and move to next file.

```
# First I loop over flux_data folder :

for (i in 1:length(flux_data)){
# second  I loop over gc data :
 for (j in 1:nrow(gc)){
```

### inside this loop,  we create if condition, in which I see if the lat and lon in gc similar to the file name in flux_data, then read it

```
    if (gc$Lat[j] & gc$Long[j] == flux_data[i]){
      my.file <- read.delim2(flux_data[i], header=TRUE, sep = "")
  
}
```

}
}

### after the loop were completed, there is no results have been made and my condition doesn’t meet, which means there is something wrong in my way of stating the condition

Comment: This is how gc data look , head(gc)
Drainage      Lat      Long
1    BONNE 43.40625 -109.7812
2    BONNE 43.40625 -109.8438
3    BONNE 43.40625 -109.9062
4    BONNE 43.46875 -109.9062
5    BONNE 43.84375 -109.9062
6    BONNE 43.90625 -109.9062

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.